# Dot Product and Angle in Degrees between two Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, vector, angle, dot-product

I would like to write a function that takes two numpy arrays with the same length and returns:

- the dot product of the two arrays
- the angle between the two vectors in degrees

The expected output is as such:

```py
print(angle_dot(np.array([0., 1.]), np.array([1., 0.])))
## (0.0, 90.0)

print(angle_dot(np.array([2., -1, 1, -2]), np.array([-1., 1.5, 3., 1])))
## (-2.5, 102.5)
```

This is what I have so far, I can't seem to get the value for the angle between the arrays correct.

```py
import numpy as np
def angle_dot(a, b):
    dot_product = round(np.dot(a, b), 1)
    angle = round(np.degrees(dot_product), 1)
    return dot_product, angle

print(angle_dot(np.array([0., 1.]), np.array([1., 0.])))
## (0.0, 0.0)

print(angle_dot(np.array([2., -1, 1, -2]), np.array([-1., 1.5, 3., 1])))
## (-2.5, -143.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle is defined using this formula (this is just one way of defining it):

```
cos(alpha) = (a . b) / (|a| * |b|)
```

So, the angle is:

```
alpha = arccos((a . b) / (|a| * |b|))
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def angle_dot(a, b):
    dot_product = np.dot(a, b)
    prod_of_norms = np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b)
    angle = round(np.degrees(np.arccos(dot_product / prod_of_norms)), 1)
    return round(dot_product, 1), angle

print(angle_dot(np.array([0., 1.]), np.array([1., 0.])))

print(angle_dot(np.array([2., -1, 1, -2]), np.array([-1., 1.5, 3., 1])))
```

Output:

```
(0.0, 90.0)
(-2.5, 102.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula for finding the angle between 2 n-dimensional arrays using the dot product is:

```
dot(a, b) = ||a|| * ||b|| * cos(theta)
theta = arccos( dot(a, b) / (||a|| * ||b||))
```

Or in numpy:

```
def angle(a, b):
    return np.degrees(np.arccos(np.dot(a, b)/ (np.linalg.norm(a) * np.linalg.norm(b))))
```